# Scala Netbeans 8.1 installation configuration

Tags: scala, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I was able to make some progress in getting Scala running on the Netbeans IDE. I am stuck with what looks like an error finding file sh.exe. I have found this file in my git directory but I have no idea where it should be in a Scala configuration.   Here is the beginning of the error message, is this familiar to someone?

> SBT -Completion:  -Exit: exit -Help: help. 
>   sbt-launch=C:\Users\William\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\modules\ext\org.netbeans.libs.sbt\1\org-scala-sbt\sbt-launch.jar
>   [ERROR] Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2,
>   The system cannot find the file specified     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the newest version of NetBeans Plugin for Scala within Windows OS during use of the Scala SBT plugin. [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) should solve the problem (after instalation don't forget to set the path/to/cygwin/bin in the Windows path variable).

Comment: When I down load the small installation program and start the install I am presented with a large category of files without one being Scala.  Do you know which packages need to be installed or a link to a document?

Comment: I think the default setting within Cygwin is sufficient. This program allows you to run basic Linux apps on Windows. It is what you need for working with SBT Scala plugin without errors. See some information about Cygwin (don't forget to add an absolute cygwin/bin path to the Windows path variable after installation).

Answer (score 0):

When I down load the small installation program and start the install I am presented with a large category of files without one being Scala.  Do you know which packages need to be installed or a link to a document?

By continuing the install without adding any additional package and then adding the path as was suggested I was able to compile a scala project in the Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE.